# Hide repeater separator item according previous value

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I'm trying only to show the repeater separator when the column named "date" from the previous item differs from the current item date.

Code below is only to facilitate the clarification of my doubt.

I have a repeater like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="tbData" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                     <th>Description</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date") %></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>    
        <tr id="rowSeparator" runat="server" visible="false">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>    
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I need only to show separator when previous date differs from current.

```
Date           Description
28/03/2016     Sample    
28/03/2016     Sample
                         => Here separator is showed.
29/03/2016     Sample
```

I've tried something like this:

```
private DateTime? lastShowedDate = null;
public bool isOtherDate; 

...

protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Separator)
    {
        //Compare last and current date                    
        isOtherDate = ((MyType)e.Item.DataItem).MyDate.Date != lastShowedDate.Value.Date;

        //Save current date for next item comparison
        lastShowedDate = ((MyType)e.Item.DataItem).MyDate;

        //Find and set control visibility
        Control separator = (Control)e.Item.FindControl("rowSeparator");

        separator.Visible = isOtherDate; 
    }
}
```

Comment: So what isn't working? The date comparison logic, or the hiding of the separator?

Comment: Hidding separator. It looks like comparison logic is ok

Comment: It look like you are trying to group items with a seperator. So maybe you should change the logic and try to use grouping logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the visibility of the separator with a bool value. When you fill the data to bind, make the required logic in order to add a True or False.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the separator is actually easier than you may think. Just simply set the visibility of the item to false. Assuming the date comparison logic works correctly, it looks like you have everything else already done.

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Separator)
    {
        //Compare last and current date                    
        isOtherDate = ((MyType)e.Item.DataItem).MyDate.Date != lastShowedDate.Value.Date;

        //Save current date for next item comparison
        lastShowedDate = ((MyType)e.Item.DataItem).MyDate;

        e.Item.Visible = isOtherDate; 
    }
}
```